# Cron Jobs - Azure Azcopy ini files

Tags: cron

We have Azure Azcopy configured on Ubuntu Server (16.04).  The ini file we have created pulls data from a cloud storage account to the local Ubuntu system.  When we run it manually, there are no issues.

However, we want to run it via a cron job every thirty minutes.

Here are the steps we have taken (we've tried variants from stack flow postings as well).  Cron is running.

crontab -e

30 * * * * root /azcopy/azcopy --config-file "azcopy_run.ini"

crontab -l lists it fine

no errors in logging

Any guidance please?

Thanks